# Why is the same fc.layer used for q,k,v in xl_net?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

Why is the same fc.layer used for q,k,v in xl_net?

```
def head_projection(h, d_model, n_head, d_head, kernel_initializer, name):
  """Project hidden states to a specific head with a 4D-shape."""
  proj_weight = tf.get_variable('{}/kernel'.format(name),
                                [d_model, n_head, d_head], dtype=h.dtype,
                                initializer=kernel_initializer)
  head = tf.einsum('ibh,hnd->ibnd', h, proj_weight)

  return head



def rel_multihead_attn(h, r, r_w_bias, r_r_bias, seg_mat, r_s_bias, seg_embed,
                       attn_mask, mems, d_model, n_head, d_head, dropout,
                       dropatt, is_training, kernel_initializer,
                       scope='rel_attn', reuse=None):
  """Multi-head attention with relative positional encoding."""

  scale = 1 / (d_head ** 0.5)
  with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=reuse):
    if mems is not None and mems.shape.ndims > 1:
      cat = tf.concat([mems, h], 0)
    else:
      cat = h

    # content heads
    q_head_h = head_projection(
        h, d_model, n_head, d_head, kernel_initializer, 'q')
    k_head_h = head_projection(
        cat, d_model, n_head, d_head, kernel_initializer, 'k')
    v_head_h = head_projection(
        cat, d_model, n_head, d_head, kernel_initializer, 'v')
```

Is it because of rel_position??
I can't figure out why even if I look at the paper

In the existing transformer model, q, k, and v are all put in separate FC layers, but I don't know why I put them in one FC layer here